# How is it possible to echo a multidimension array value witout loop in php

Tags: arrays, echo

I have a multidimension array, in fact a 2 dimension array, I like to echo all the value of the second index... something like that : $cars[0][0]

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",100,96),
  array("BMW",60,59),
  array("Toyota",110,100)
  );
```

$cars[0][0] will get me : Volvo. what i need is : **Volvo 100 96**. Is there is a way to echo this ?.. not print_r or var_dump. does a php function exist to do that ?

---

let's say now the RESULT array is $cars... 3 sub array value... i what them out. based on answer i try that :

```
foreach ($cars as $singleArray => $key) {
    $result = "";
    $result = implode(' ', $singleArray[$key]);
    echo '# '. $key .' '. $result .'<br/>';
}
```

**there is an ERROR : Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/studiot/public_html/previsite.com/data/array2.php on line 46
 Array**

---

i have done it like this :

```
foreach ($cars as $singleArray) {
    $keyValue ++;
    $result = "";
    $result .= implode(' ', $singleArray);
    echo '(# '. $keyValue .') -> '. $result .'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply implode the array you want to output with spaces:

```
echo implode(' ', $cars[0]);
// Volvo 100 96
```

Docs: http://nz1.php.net/function.implode

> EDIT

I see you've tried to use a `foreach` loop, your syntax is wrong for it. foreach parameters are **input array** as **array key** => **array value**. So you'll implode the value (which is another array. Like this:

```
foreach ($cars as $key => $value) {
    $result = implode(' ', $value);
    echo '# '. $key .' '. $result .'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: GOOD!, thanks, but of the return array contain more that one index.. is it possible to get them all witout loop ?

Comment: just like echo implode(' ', $cars[0]); and echo implode(' ', $cars[1]);, echo implode(' ', $cars[2]);

Comment: Without a loop... you'll need to do what you've just dont in that last comment. Why don't you want to use a loop?

Comment: Obviously i dont understand : foreach